# Cannot move array of objects

Tags: modifiers, rigidbody

I tried to create an array of these mini figurines and then separate them so that they can be moved individually. I applied rigid body settings to one of the figurines, setting it as active and copied settings to the whole group. Afterwards, not only was I unable to move the inidividual figurines but I was also unable to move the whole group. They would just sling back to their original position. Then when I tried to animate objects and have them fall through this funnel, they remained static. Please advise on where I could have gone wrong. Thanks!

[image]

11/10/20 - So I tried redoing the process per [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqsGrYIK5k0&ab_channel=WasiqWiqar) tutorial with building an array, applying the rigid body settings, and then separating by loose parts, but the parts will not even fall from gravity when I play the animation. As suggested below in two comments, I checked to see if there were any keyframes denoted by a diamond on the timeline according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZJswvw9wEs&ab_channel=Blender) video I saw. Thank you guys for all the feedback thus far. Still learned a lot!

11/10/20 - So in a different workspace, I tested the same exact process on an obj file with more reasonable results apart from the objects slightly passing through the base. The animation is incredibly slow though!

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you created a keyframe at their original position?

Comment: Side note, when you fix this problem, don't forget to put the origin of these objects to their individual center of mass, else your simulation will be wonky

Comment: @moonboots, I had to look up what a keyframe was, but no, I don't thiiiink I created one, at least not intentionally.

Comment: @Gorgious, thanks for the tip! Will there be an issue with animation if I set the origin to the geometry as opposed to center of mass?

Comment: No I don't think there will be a problem. But what you should to help the framerate is create a lower poly of your mesh and use that as the simulated mesh under a parent empty

Comment: @Gorgious, would you clarify "under a parent empty"? Sorry, I am a complete noob and only know have created an Empty --> Plane Axes before. Is that what you meant followed by setting that empty entity as the parent of this low-poly modified mesh? Thanks again!